# How to fix QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

How to fix the `QGraphicsScene`? I mean, how to disable auto centering? When I try to move an object along the X axis to the right, and then return it to the left by the same axis, the center changes...

Comment: Start by posting a [mcve] showing an example of your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020906/6401403